# GraphQL Apollo iOS 14 upload fails

Tags: swift, graphql, upload, apollo, ios14

According to the tutorial of [Apollo iOS](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/ios/mutations/), my upload action got error messages at my iOS 14 devices.

Here is my source code:

```
func post() {
    guard let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "a", withExtension: "txt") else {return}
    let file = try! GraphQLFile(fieldName: "file", originalName: "a.txt", mimeType: "text/plain", fileURL: url)
    Network.main.apollo.upload(operation: TestMutation(file: "a"), files: [file]) {r in
        print(r)
    }
}
```

At file "Test.graphql":

```
mutation Test ($file: Upload!) {
    uploadFile(file: $file) {
        url
    }
}
```

The console error message:

```
success(Apollo.GraphQLResult<MyApp.TestMutation.Data>(
  data: Optional(MyApp.TestMutation.Data(resultMap: ["uploadFile": nil])), 
  errors: Optional([Internal server error]),
  extensions: nil,
  source: Apollo.GraphQLResult<MyApp.TestMutation.Data>.Source.server, 
  dependentKeys: Optional(Set(["MUTATION_ROOT.uploadFile(file:a)"]))
))
```

The posts success at both Android and postMan. I don't know why it fails at iOS.

Is it a bug of Apollo iOS? Or am I doing something wrong? Thanks.

Comment: IDK IOS ... but code differs to example ... `GraphQLFile ... else return`, not `try!` ... check raw network request, does it contain encoded file?

Comment: I found it is the problem of Authentication!